# Eclipse is freezing itself before getting started

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I've been trying to open Eclipse to start my work today, and it freezes everytime during load.

My Eclipse is Helios. Someone told me I should remove a file called .lock from .metadata folder, but still didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea of how do I "melt" this thing up?

ps: I opened it yesterday with no problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something is wrong with your workspace. I typically remove current and create new one in such case. It usually takes up to 5 minutes (if I have to add 20 projects). In most cases it takes less.

Comment: Something might have happened with my workspace, i just created another one and download projects from svn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to start Eclipse with a -clean parameter? Sometimes this can resolve some issues..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a (big) problem with a plugin in Eclipse.. because project plugins or runtimes will execute later.

Create a new workspace and repimport your projects from your old workspace. If you have a vcs, you can re-checkout them.

Answer (score 1):

Start it with the `-clean` option.

It should take a bit longer (depends on your eclipse configuration and workspace, but if nothing is really broken, it will get it to work).

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something similar when launching Eclipse after having to force close it for some reason. 
If it always hangs when loading the SVN plugin — like in your screenshot — it is likely to be related to that. In this case I suggest the following:

- back up your current workspace
- launch Eclipse with the -data command line argument to specify a different workspace folder
- if Eclipse starts up successfully, try to import your projects from the original workspace **or** even better from SVN